# Logging instance class

Tags: python, python-3.x, class

I am in the midst of re-organising my code as I have just understood the concept of using classes. 
My question is that is there a way to simplify the call to my logger class? I have tried using the @property but then I wouldn't be able to use the @classmethod.

```
from yaml import safe_load
from logging import getLogger
from logging.config import dictConfig


class create_logger:

    def __init__(self, logger_instance):
        self.logger_instance = logger_instance

    @classmethod
    def parse_logger(cls):
        with open('../log.yaml', 'r') as file:
            logging_cfg = safe_load(file.read())

        dictConfig(logging_cfg)
        new_logger = getLogger("LOGApp")

        return cls(new_logger)
```

```
# How do I simplify this call?
application_logger = create_logger.parse_logger().logger_instance
```

Comment: do you need this to be configured multiple times? couldn't you just run the content of parse_logger at initialization once and then just call getLogger("LOGApp") whenever you need that logger? Python's loggers are global, getLogger will always return the same named logger

Comment: It's unclear to me what the purpose of the class is. If you don't need OOP structure to your code, there's nothing that requires that you use it. Python modules are perfectly good enough for encapsulating related code, you don't need to put things in a class if they'd make more sense as module-level functions.

Comment: Thanks for your inputs, I will just make it into a stand alone function. I guess I got carried away and wanted to turn everything into classes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually have left it as a module function instead of making it a class.

```
from yaml import safe_load
from logging import getLogger
from logging.config import dictConfig

def st_logger():

    with open('../log.yaml', 'r') as file:
        logging_cfg = safe_load(file.read())

    dictConfig(logging_cfg )
    new_logger = getLogger("LOGApp")

    return new_logger
```